# passing Edit text data from android to php

Tags: php, android

I need to read data from an external database with hundreds of items. What I did so far is that I wrote the php query which returns all the items, so for i have done

php:

```
$db_host  = "host";
$db_uid  = "username";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name  = "person"; 
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

android:

```
String url = "http://localhost/index.php";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*
     * StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network
     * access on the application's main thread
     */

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hospital);

    byear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);

    // define the action when user clicks on submit button
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the
            // name "birthyear" and its value submitted by user
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            data = byear.getText().toString();
            // define the parameter
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
            String response = null;

            // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters
            try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(

                url,
                postParameters);

                // store the result returned by PHP script that runs
                // MySQL query
                String result = response.toString();

                // parse json data
                try {
                    returnString = "";
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag", "id: " + json_data.getInt("id")
                                + ", name: " + json_data.getString("name")

                        );
                        // Get an output to the screen


                        returnString += "\n" + "Name ="
                                + json_data.getString("name") + "\n"
                                + "Contact number = "
                                + json_data.getInt("contact") + "\n"

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                try {
                    tv.setText(returnString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in Display!" + e.toString());
                    ;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag",
                        "Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

My question is how can I pass the data from edit text android to php query so the query will only return the proper items only

Comment: In your code at android side your using "data" as a key to send your information to php but at php side there is no key exact name "data" so how php will get information from android

so my suggestion is please use same key "data" in php too then only it will work

Comment: i have no more knowledge about php. can u demo please. how to write.. thanx advance

Comment: use my updated answer it will surely work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data to php use postParameters :

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePairs("id",data));
```

In your php script add

```
if(isset($_POST['id']){
    var id = $_POST['id'];
    // do db operation here
}
```

with id = your data id and data = your data.

Comment: if i want to query on button click what should i do..?

Comment: just call your CustomHttpClient.execyute on your onClick listener. Your code above already send post method to your php when you click submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var_data=$_REQUEST['data'];
    print($var_data);
```

use above 2 lines in your php code at line number 1 so it will print android data associated with key "data"

```
 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to write respective php script Then you can use this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://Your Url");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid",username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename",filename));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Make sure that the field name in your table in server side is "uid" and "filename" respectively.
For more information see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).